# Где хранить текущие данные программы?

Tags: java, ооп, android, архитектура

Мое приложение имеет некие динамические пути, которые формируются при каждом запуске. И, к которым мне нужно иметь доступ из любой части программы. Сейчас я пользуюсь объектом `static`. Меня все устраивает. Однако в статье на Хабре не рекомендуется хранить данные в `static`, связано с жизненным циклом Activity.

Остается либо `property` файл, либо `SQLite`, но меня смущает "тяжесть" этих способов. Быть может есть еще какие варианты? Или все-таки стоит остановиться на `SQLite`?

Comment: Почитайте про сериализацию, если необходимо хранить большие структурированные данные

Comment: @Krom Stern, почему же нет ответа? 1 - `SharedPreferences`, 2 - `БД`, 3 - `@Bean`. В моем случае отдам предпочтение все таки `БД`. Но и `@Bean` - интересный вариант, по крайней мере, мне не знакомый.

Comment: Мой комментарий был адресован BORSHEVIK до того как его ответ перенесли в комментарии.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё зависит от объёма и сложности ваших данных. Если вам достаточно хранить строки/массивы строк/числа, то можно пользоваться `SharedPreferences`:

```
//сохраняем строку в файл внутренней директории приложения
SharePreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
pref.edit().putString("key", "value").commit();

//получаем ранее сохранённые данные
String savedData=pref.getString("key");
```

Если что-то сложнее, то да - используйте `БД`.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого придумали паттерн Singleton.

```
@EBean(scope = Scope.Singleton)
public class MySingltoneBean {
    //Тут прописываем геттеры сеттеры и прочие методы доступа к общим переменным
}
```

Теперь, когда нам надо воспользоваться нашими общими данными из Activity достаточно в нем определить

```
@Bean MySingltoneBean mySingltoneBean;
```

Answer (score 0):

Я использую немного иной способ (самый легкий): создаю Java класс (не `Activity`, а просто класс) и в нем храню статические переменные. Так они доступным всем и отовсюду, а так же не зависят от жизненного цикла `Activity`. Главное в этом способе — простота.

---

Пример:

```
class Resources {
    public static int myNumber = 2334595;
}
```

Теперь переменную `myNumber` может получить и изменить любая активность (и фрагменты, и все остальные).

---

Еще хорош способ, который описали выше. Но тот способ - для хранения данных, которые должны сохранится после закрытия приложения, а мой — во время работы приложения (Вы же сказали, что они создаются при запуске).

Comment: Ваш способ имеет свой недостаток, а именно GC всё равно модет удалить нужные данные при определённых обстоятеоьствах

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, а... что такое GC?

Comment: @bukashka101, верояно garbage collection