# Получение переменой из одного класса в другое Activity

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases

Пытаюсь реализовать платное удаление рекламы. Для платежей использую [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)
.

Создал активити, в котором пользователь производит оплату, после чего записывается переменная `isRemoveAds = true;`.

Как передать её из активити, в котором совершается в платеж в любое другое активити?

Пытаюсь так:

```
final PaymentActivity payment = new PaymentActivity (MainActivity.this);
if(payment.isRemoveAds==false) {
            Appodeal.show(this, Appodeal.BANNER_TOP);
}
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> this class should provide a default constructor

И **PaymentActivity** в Manifest подсвечивает:

> has no default constructor

Насколько я понял эта ошибка возникает из-за аргументов **PaymentActivity**.

**PaymentActivity:**

```
public class PaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{

    private final Context myContext;
    BillingProcessor bp;
    boolean isRemoveAds = false;

    public PaymentActivity(Context context) {
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_payment);
        String base64EncodedPublicKey =
                "KEY";

        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, base64EncodedPublicKey, this);

        ImageView background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.payment_bg).asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true).format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888).centerCrop().into(background);

        ImageView btnRemoveAds = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.removeAds);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(R.drawable.quit_button).asBitmap().format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888).into(btnRemoveAds);
        btnRemoveAds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bp.purchase(PaymentActivity.this, "android.test.purchased");

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
   public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {
        isRemoveAds = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (bp != null) {
            bp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Как передать `isRemoveAds` в другие активити?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трогать конструкторы фрагментов и активити нельзя - система будет кидать исключения. Это произойдёт потому что система сама создаёт экземпляры этих классов и сама ими манипулирует для поддержания жизненного цикла.

Могу посоветовать сделать иначе - при успешной покупке записать в `SharedPreferences` `boolean` значение и его получать в других активити.

Либо запускать активити с покупками через `startActivityForResult` - тогда в вызвавшей активити буедт вызван после завершения покупки метод `onActivityResult` и в нём вы можете получить результат переданный из запускаемой активити.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но, простите, у вас не будет примера использования `SharedPreferences` с `boolean` значением? @ЮрийСПб

Comment: @ЛевНауменко, вот пример для строк. Для Boolean - тоже самое. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461158/17609

Comment: Спасибо! Работает, но есть одно но, когда приложение удаляется или удаляется кэш переменная сбрасывается. Есть ли какие-то способы решения этого? @ЮрийСПб

Comment: @ЛевНауменко, в теории гугл по умолчанию всё это пишет в облако и автоматом восстанавливает. На мой взгляд эта фича не работает. Таким образом, сохранение меж переустановками может обеспечить только серверная часть и система логина. Так можно связывать пары юзер-настройки

Comment: А можно ли как-то вызвать `onProductPurchased` при запуске `MainActivity`? Просто переменная вновь записывается, когда я просто обращаюсь к `onProductPurchased` ничего заново не оплачивая. @ЮрийСПб